# How do I solve this integral with derivate

Tags: integration

How do I solve this:$$\int_{-1}^{1}\lvert f'(x) \rvert $$ and f(x) is $$ e^{x^2} $$

Comment: Try actually computing the derivative. Does it ever change sign?

Comment: It changes the sign for x<0 does that mean that I'll break the integral in to two from -1 to 0 and  0-1 ?

Comment: That should do the trick.

Comment: It's impossible. There is no symbol of integration so we don't know what to integrate with respect to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to note that $f(x) = e^{x^2}$ is an even function so its derivative must be odd. This implies $\int_{-1}^1 |f'(x)| = 2\int_0^1 f'(x) \, dx = 2[f(1) - f(0)] = 2(e-1)$.

Answer (score 1):

$\int_{-1}^{1}\lvert 2xe^{x^2}\rvert  = \int_{-1}^{0}\lvert 2xe^{x^2}\rvert +\int_{0}^{1}\lvert 2xe^{x^2}\rvert  $. Now, the $2xe^{x^2}$ is always negative on $[-1,0]$ and always positive on $[0,1]$. So this then becomes $$-\int_{-1}^{0} 2xe^{x^2}+\int_{0}^{1} 2xe^{x^2}  $$  $$=e^{1}+e^{1} -2 = 2e-2$$

Answer (score 1):

First note that $f'(x) = 2xe^{x^{2}}$; so $f'$ is symmetric about the line $x = 0$. Then 
$$
\int_{-1}^{1}|f'| = \int_{-1}^{1}|2xe^{x^{2}}|dx = 2\int_{-1}^{1}|xe^{x^{2}}|dx = 4\int_{0}^{1}xe^{x^{2}}dx.
$$
Note that $xe^{x^{2}} = \frac{(Dx^{2})}{2}e^{x^{2}}$; so $\int xe^{x^{2}}dx = e^{x^{2}}/2$ + constant.

Comment: So I could've gotten the answer by using the fact that an uneven integral centered in 0 is 2xintegral?Thank you

Comment: @Lola, Thanks to the absolute value function.